# Data exchange between android app and web service

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails

I have an Android app with some data (consisting in latitude and longitude) and a RAILS web service with a MySQL database... I want to know how to send this data to my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an web server with logic implementation to accept/update/delete data from mysql server either by using Java/PHP etc...You need to specify internet permission in your manifest file. And follow the link below for more detail [how to make PHP server sends data to an Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387212/how-to-make-php-server-sends-data-to-an-android-device)

Answer (score 0):

Rails exposes REST APIs that you can use to send data to your server. There should be an api that accepts post requests and updates the data on your web application's database. Ask your rails developer for the url.

Comment: can you give me a little example of this... I'm not the one working on rails so I don't really know much of it

Comment: Did you ask your Rails developer whether a RESTful API is in place?

Answer (score 0):

Make a REST post/put call to your webservice.You can use Android httpclient to make a connection. The api is available here

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html

As always, don't forget to turn on your internet permission and perform your network tasking within AsyncTask or another thread to prevent UI thread blocking.